# Wordpress navigation IE 9 and below not working on home but works on rest of the pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

Hey guys I would really appreciate help. I created a custom wordpress theme and the site is bikebuckscounty.com. Only enough on all IE9 and below the header looks all messed up on the home page. But on the same IE9 and less if you go to a subpage the exact same navigation works perfectly. For example here is the home bikebuckscounty.net and here is a subpage http://bikebuckscounty.com/safety-tips/

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple: view and compare source on those two pages. I see a bunch of out of place Javascripts.

It's best if you learn to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) or [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx) to view and work with the CSS and HTML and see what Javascript is loading in your theme.

Comment: The thing is I'm using wordpress so they should come out the exact same. It looks normal on all modern browsers